# How to add data from the database table to the list and display it in "CategoryPicker"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem ,I want to add data from the database table to the list and display it in "CategoryPicker"
now I have my category make in View like this:

```
div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, "Type")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, new List<SelectListItem>
        {
        new SelectListItem { Text="Funny", Value="Funny" },
        new SelectListItem { Text="Serious", Value="Serious" },
        new SelectListItem { Text="Stupid", Value="Stupid" }
        }, "Give a category of meme", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

I want to look like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkcUR.jpg
I create model Memy and Category

```
 public partial class Memy
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [HiddenInput]
        public int Id_mema { get; set; }
        public string Autor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [HiddenInput]
        public string coverImg { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [HiddenInput]
        public DateTime? releaseDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? modifyDate { get; set; }
        public int? Like { get; set; }
        public int? Dislike { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Categories
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int IdCategory { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string NameCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Provided link not working

Comment: weird ,at my place everything  is working what kind of browse are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to get the list from the database

```
public class helpers
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategories()
    {
        // your context
        return new SelectList(myContext.Categories.OrderBy(x => x.NameCategory ), 
                                                      "IdCategory ", "NameCategory ");
    }
}
```

Then link to this using something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, helpers.GetCategories(),
                  "Give a category of meme")
```

Comment: I have this error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'helpers.GetCategories()'  and I can not find any good solution

Comment: Make sure you have the keyword `static` in the method signature as in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I made like you wrote

```
@model MemeGenerator.Models.Memy
@using <insert memy controller namespace here>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateMeme";
}
<h2>CreateMeme</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Memy", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, "Title")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Give title" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, "Description")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Give description" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, MemyController.GetCategories(),
                   "Give a category of meme")
    </div>
```

and in MemyController

```
 public class MemyController : Controller
    {

        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        //1 MB
        const long fileMaxSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        memyContext db = new memyContext();
        public class helpers
        {
            private readonly memyContext _context;

            public helpers(memyContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }

            public  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategories()
            {
                // your context

                return new SelectList(_context.Categories.OrderBy(x => x.NameCategory), "IdCategory ", "NameCategory ");
            }
        }
```

and I have this error:The name "GetCategories" does not exist in the current context.Somebody have that problem?

Comment: ok but what kind of namespace reference I should add here in order to work everything ?

Comment: I add namspace from memyContext but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: I've updated my answer - you need a reference to the class that the method belongs to and then add `@using namespace` for the namespace of the helper class.

Comment: I edited my answer I added what you suggest in MemyController and tryying add @using helpers but it not help ,i do not understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Sorry @bart - I should have been clearer. The namespace I gave was only an example/place holder - it should be the same namespace as `MemyController`. Also ensure you update the method as well to `MemyController.GetCategories`

Comment: so I should go back to first method which uou show me without class helper ,and after this it have to work? I added @using EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb.Controllers-namespace from MemyController

Comment: I've updated your answer above to the suggested values. You now need to put in the correct namespace in the `@using` line.

Comment: holy ,I made this and now I have this error: No overload for method 'GetCategories' takes 1 arguments

Comment: 'Delete Model from the call'-what you mean? ,sorry but I don't understand

Comment: `GetCategories` had `Model` has a parameter. This was an error as not required here. I've updated your answer.

Comment: If you look at my answer I wrote `m => m.Category`. You have `m=>m`